# I don't find birthday and gander of user. When user register by google sign in I only find name, email, photo of user. I using node js server

Tags: node.js, express

I using node server and I need birthday and gender but I only get name, email,
and photo. I using this (@react-oauth/google) library in frontend. I using react in
the frontend. When I send api request from frontend I get only name, email, and
photo. And here is the backend code. So please I need the solution of my
problem.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');

const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);

const users = [];

function upsert(array, item) {
  const i = array.findIndex((_item) => _item.email === item.email);
  if (i > -1) array[i] = item;
  else array.push(item);
}

app.post('/api/google-login', async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.body;
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: token,
    audience: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  });
  const { name, email, picture } = ticket.getPayload();
  upsert(users, { name, email, picture });
  console.log(ticket.getPayload());
  res.status(201);
  res.json({ name, email, picture });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server is ready at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 5000}`
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of @react-oauth
I'm thrilled that you gave it a try.

Actually, I didn't try to get user age before , But I just found something that will guide you in the right direction I wish.

- Any extra information required from the user regardless of email, name, and pic (public ones) we need the permission from them
- you need to add scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read to read user's gender and same for birthday
- All scopes available here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes | your need is under People API
- Enable Google People API https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/browse?project=ferrous-terrain-348520&q=people
- Generate API Key we will need it later when requesting from google people API
- you can find people `GET` API [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2F118264670396449168345%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22genders%22%2C%22sources%22%3A%5B%22READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE%22%5D%7D), I figured first request from there sidebar playground and network from dev tools.

I will give you an example I tried on the client, But I believe you can achieve this also on the server with [google-apis-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis)

- when using in your App, make the two requests with Promise.all, It's just like that for demo
- Add you API_KEY
- specify fields that you need to get

```js
const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: async tokenResponse => {
      console.log(tokenResponse);
      const userInfo = await axios
        .get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo', {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse.access_token}` },
        })
        .then(res => res.data);

      const gender = await axios
        .get(
          `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?key=${<YOU_API_KEY}&personFields=genders`,
          {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse.access_token}` },
          },
        )
        .then(res => res.data);

      console.log(userInfo, gender);
    },
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read',
  });
```

I'm sorry but to specify scopes we need to use google authorization flow that can't be used with the personalized button, But I believe that you can do fetching the user info like you are doing and same for age. you can replace /me to /<USER_ID>

and your frontend can use the personalized button as it is.

I just found that you can do it without API key
`https://content-people.googleapis.com/v1/people/<USER_ID>?personFields=genders`

I think you got the idea

Comment: Thanks, Dear. Now I have got the gender and birthday of the user. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Up vote for future readers

Comment: And mark as solved as good practice, please! I spent all day looking for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can check their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth?hl=en)


They do not return gender and birthdate. Here is an example of a full response containing the information that you can use (from the documentation link above)

```
{
 // These six fields are included in all Google ID Tokens.
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953",

 // These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
}
```